# O que é um byte array?

Tags: c#, array, unity3d, byte

O que é o byte array em Unity? Sei que armazenamos dados que podem ser convertidos em bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é exclusivo do Unity, embora nele tenha algumas utilidades específicas, até não poderia falar em Unity e sim em cada caso que o Unity usa.

Como todo *array*, ele é uma sequência de dados de um determinado tipo, e nesse caso é de um *byte* simples. Você pode colocar o que quiser ali. Virtualmente pode colocar qualquer informação em um `byte[]` porque qualquer dado é uma sequência de *bytes*. Pode ser um texto, um executável, uma imagem, um vídeo, um som, um padrão qualquer, algo com um formato específico, não importa.

Alguns objetos podem ser gerados ou armazenados de forma genérica como um *array* de *bytes*. Exemplo:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Start() {
        // Create a 16x16 texture with PVRTC RGBA4 format
        // and fill it with raw PVRTC bytes.
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(16, 16, TextureFormat.PVRTC_RGBA4, false);
        // Raw PVRTC4 data for a 16x16 texture. This format is four bits
        // per pixel, so data should be 16*16/2=128 bytes in size.
        // Texture that is encoded here is mostly green with some angular
        // blue and red lines.
        byte[] pvrtcBytes = new byte[] {
            0x30, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xe7, 0x30, 0xaa, 0x7f, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xf9, 0x40, 0xbc, 0x7f,
            0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x30, 0x02, 0x05, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xf4, 0x30, 0x03, 0x06,
            0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xf7, 0x40, 0xaa, 0x7f, 0x32, 0xf2, 0x02, 0xa8, 0xe7, 0x30, 0xff, 0xff,
            0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x40, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xe9, 0x40, 0x9f, 0xff,
            0x5b, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xca, 0x6a, 0x0f, 0x30, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff, 0xca, 0x68, 0x0f, 0x30,
            0xaa, 0x94, 0x90, 0x40, 0xba, 0x5b, 0xaf, 0x68, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xca, 0x58, 0x0f, 0x20,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x40, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xdb, 0x41, 0xff, 0xff,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe8, 0x40, 0x01, 0x1c, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0x40, 0xff, 0xff,
        };
        // Load data into the texture and upload it to the GPU.
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(pvrtcBytes);
        tex.Apply();
        // Assign texture to renderer's material.
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Unity.cs).

[Fonte](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html).

Esse exemplo monta um padrão de imagem que criará um objeto de textura para usar em objetos de cena do jogo. Esses *bytes* acabam, formando uma forma de desenho de alguma forma, eles indicam onde deve ter um determinado tom de cor para simular uma superfície hipotética. Em um código real poderia ir mudando esses números, que foram escritos em notação hexadecimal, mas são número como qualquer outro podendo ir de 0 à 255, e depois de mudar pode ver mudanças na textura que é aplicada ao jogo. Uma textura é uma sequência de *bytes*.

Comment: Obrigada amigo! Mas no caso, qualquer dado nele colocado acaba convertendo para sua respectiva sequência de bytes?

Comment: Nada é convertido, pelo menos sem mandar. Ele **é** uma sequência de bytes, como todo *array* é uma sequência de alguma coisa. O que pode fazer é pegar essa sequência e converter para algo com um significado especial como foi feito nesse código que converte para uma textura, ou pode fazer o oposto em algum lugar e pegar um objeto específico e tratar como uma sequência de bytes.

Comment: Muito obrigada novamente! Ajudou bastante.